# cxf setting Nonce and created in SOAP wsse header

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse, wsse

I wanted to inject Nonce and Created element in WSSE security header using CXF.

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-6">
            <wsse:Username>==Username==</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">==Password==</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">===EncodeString===</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2016-05-20T10:51:24.795Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

I'm using org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JOutInterceptor class to populate the CXF headers. But this populates only **wsse:Username** and **wsse:Password**. I wanted **wsse:Nonce** and **wsse:Created** as well in my header.
Which Approach I should take to populate above elements in my security header?

Below is the code which I'm using to populate this,

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, "UsernameToken");
properties.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "userName-Text");
properties.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
properties.put(WSHandlerConstants.MUST_UNDERSTAND, "true");
properties.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_REF, new CustomWSPasswordCallback(passwordText));

WSS4JOutInterceptor wss4jOutInterceptor = new WSS4JOutInterceptor();
wss4jOutInterceptor.setProperties(properties);
```

I appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Ashish Mishra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your properties if you are using WSS4J < 2.0:

```
properties.put(WSHandlerConstants.ADD_UT_ELEMENTS, WSConstants.NONCE_LN + " " + WSConstants.CREATED_LN);
```

if using WSS4J >= 2.0 then it should be:

```
properties.put(WSHandlerConstants.ADD_USERNAMETOKEN_NONCE, "true");
properties.put(WSHandlerConstants.ADD_USERNAMETOKEN_CREATED, "true");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. My WSS4J < 2.0 hence above didn't worked for me. But you suggestion help me find out the things. I'm posting my answer as below. Thanks!

Comment: This post helped me solve the same problem, thanks! However, I noticed that WSHandlerConstants inherits those constants from org.apache.wss4j.common.ConfigurationConstants - you'd be better off referencing them directly from ConfigurationConstants as this will work with either the Stax or Dom implementations of the WSS4J interceptor. The above implementation forces you to have the DOM module on the buildpath.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to inject Nonce and Created element in WSSE header through adding below property in my property map,

```
properties.put(WSHandlerConstants.ADD_UT_ELEMENTS, WSConstants.NONCE_LN + " " + WSConstants.CREATED_LN);
```

This worked for me.

For more you can refer http://tobiasbayer.com/post/apache-cxf-usernametoken-authentication-with-nonce/

Thanks Guys.
Ashish Mishra